# Initial Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

Programming Language Design and Implementation Stack Exchange is just over two weeks into private beta, which means it’s time to start thinking about what comes next: the election to choose your first moderators.

### What does it take to be a Moderator?

Prior to 2018, [moderators were handpicked by staff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), and referred to as *pro-tempore* or *pro-tem* mods, because they were intended to serve only until the community could run its own elections. The Community Management team would look for users who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- Have an eye for content that should be flagged, closed, or removed, and act on that within the expectations of the community and Stack Exchange generally

### Electing your moderators

In 2018, however, beta sites began electing their own pro-tem moderators, joining community-elected moderators on network sites that have left their beta phase. The process is mostly the same, but if you’re interested in the full details, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections).

Today, I’m announcing this site’s first pro-tem election. If you are interested in nominating yourself, you are invited to state your intention to do so in an answer here. Additionally, if you feel someone would be a good fit as a moderator on this site, feel free to use an answer to this question to support them and encourage them to run. The timeline:

- Starting on the Monday following the site moving into public beta (week 1), users can nominate themselves in the election page. Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On the following Monday (week 2), if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on meta on the following Tuesday (week 3) (or the one after that, on week 4, if we need to extend the nomination period).

#### NOTES:

- **This is not an official election nomination thread.** It’s just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination here.
- **This does not mean that the site has been cleared to leave private beta.** The dates for the election are provisional and subject to change, and the election as a whole is dependent on Programming Language Design and Implementation meeting the requirements to progress from private into public beta.
- **In order to be considered as a candidate**, applicants must comply with the requirements listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/1116284), specifically:

  - Have at least 300 reputation.
  - Be "in good standing", i.e. not have been [suspended on any site in the past year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).
  - Be [18 years of age or older](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357378/355458), or be 18 years of age or older by the end of the election.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Are the requirements the same ("must be over 18", for example)

Comment: @UndoneStudios They're exactly the same.

Answer (score 16):

If Adám decides to run (which he has expressed his desire to), I would totally support him. He is a professional (head of language design at Dyalog), has much activity on this site, and has supported the site from its earliest beginnings.

Comment: Sure. I should maybe mention that I've been active on Stack Exchange for almost 10 years, and have been moderating a constantly-in-use programming language themed room for 6 years. While I am definitely less *avid* than many others, I do have *constancy*: Since the site is relevant for my work, I'll be here most of the day, most days, able to step in and assist with reasonable response time.

Answer (score 8):

I would unconditionally run in the election:

- As stated in my [github profile](https://github.com/Lyxal), I'm highly interested in and passionate about the design and implementation of programming languages. The way words are lexed and parsed into meaninful constructs computers can then execute is truly fascinating.
- My experience with programming lanugage design is mostly in the form of esolangs/golfing languages [for example, my most popular language, Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal). However, I've also spent a good amount of time diving into how practical languages are parsed.
- For moderation, I'd be around a lot to handle any flags/issues that are raised on the site, as well as being able to help build the site culture.
- Also, I'm around during the hours when everyone else is asleep - UTC+10 (UTC+11 during October through Match) means my afternoon is most people's midnight. It's always good to have a diverse timezone spread where it's always a non-night time for someone on the mod team.

Answer (score 7):

I am interested in this.

I am an academic programming languages researcher mostly focusing on building language features and interfaces to broaden access to programming languages, and most of my activity on the network has been on Unix & Linux since nine or so years ago. I am very keen on this site flourishing and I'd like to help that come to be as a community service, both because I hope for it to be useful to me, and because there's a lot of folk knowledge about PL design that is currently hard to come across without knowing someone who knows it, but can be collated well in the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 6):

### I am interested in becoming a moderator

I already participate in some moderation activities such as monitoring [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) (prior to the strike) to flag spam and rude/abusive posts. As a moderator I would try my best to handle those and other flags quickly to keep the site clean and safe. Despite the strike, I would still care for and serve Programming Language Design & Implementation as a moderator. I am currently, however, on strike on the large sites such as Stack Overflow, where the management will feel the effects the most.

Most of the time a new site opens, the site is for a niche technology or niche topic that I do not know about. This site was different. I witnessed the birth of a site that I can actually participate in, and best of all, I finally get some feedback on all those features that my vision of a perfect programming language could have. This site has helped me grow and understand what it takes to create a real programming language.

I will offer my services to help the site grow in return as a moderator.

Answer (score 4):

### I am interested

I'm Silvio Mayolo, also known as "Mercerenies" on some other sites. I'm a programming language designer and enthusiast who has designed six different languages (ranging from esoteric, to golfing, to general-purpose). I've been a member of Stack Overflow for nearly ten years, and of the Code Golf Stack Exchange site for nearly that long. I would love to take a bigger role in helping this community grow and blossom.

Answer (score 2):

I am happy to run, even if only to ensure that there are enough candidates in the running to make the election competitive. I would be honoured to be a moderator, and I would be more than happy to lose an election to good candidates if that is the will of the community.

If it helps, I was a Usenet moderator back in the day.

Comment: FYI beta moderator elections don't need to be competitive - if there aren't enough candidates they appoint everyone who ran without an election.

Answer (score 2):

I would be glad to be a moderator here! I’ll post a nomination once they’re open.

Answer (score 1):

If we are short on numbers I would be willing to volunteer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in being a moderator. I've recently been bamboozled into developing DSLs in my professional work and so I've been delving deeper into custom PLs.